# Real time preview in browser

Tags: html, css, browser, preview, live-preview

I want to know that how I can view my codes in browser at same time when typing codes just like codepen.io 
I am using sublime text 3 and chrome browser please suggest me how to achieve it..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [htmledit](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) when you type code it will produce results without even refreshing the page, it works great in chrome as well.

Comment: It works like a text editor, minus syntax highlighting and such, but it works conveniently if you want immediate results from your browser while typing in code.

Comment: But can I do it with sublime text 3 or dreamviewer 8 ?

Comment: sublime 3 will not live feed while you code, dreamviewer would work but you would have to pay for the software.

Comment: for offline your best bet would be notepad++

Comment: How to do it with notepad++ cause I have notepad++

Comment: click run, then click run with chrome and the live page will appear with your work. It should not require online because it is pulling up a page based on your html file and not a live site.

Comment: Will it work live I mean will it show result while typing

Comment: this article: http://www.ampercent.com/how-to-preview-html-in-notepad/16844/ has instructions that go in depth with offline text editor coding and being able to view results while typing in notepad++

Answer (score 0):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) has a great live previewer, it's an offline text editor so give it a shot, in my opinion it is also a lot better than Sublime Text!

Comment: But I think it Is online

Comment: Brackets is not online, both the program and the previewer is offline as the previewer makes use of the localhost (127.0.0.1) to display/alter the output.

Comment: No I used it but whenever I was online live preview was working fine and then when I was offline it didn't work it shows me some error

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine when you're completely offline! So I'm not sure what error you had, but what you're saying is false as it works via your localhost and not any online service or processor.

As mentioned before, Brackets can completely be used offline. And what reason do you even want to be completely offline when working with websites? That doesn't really make sense to me.